# Changing TextMessageEncodingBindingElement to utf-8 not working "Fixed"

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, .net-5

Even i create a new CustomBinding and overriding the textEncoding parametre to utf-8 the message reached to BeforeSend() function is always utf-16.
The real exception was **Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'run'.** but i thought it was from encoding cause when i tried it in SoapUI with utf-16 it doesn't work.

```
 var security = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
    security.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.TripleDes;
    security.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Strict;
    security.IncludeTimestamp = true;
    security.KeyEntropyMode = SecurityKeyEntropyMode.CombinedEntropy;
    security.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10;
    security.LocalClientSettings.DetectReplays = true;
    security.LocalClientSettings.MaxClockSkew = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
    security.LocalClientSettings.ReplayWindow = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
    security.LocalClientSettings.TimestampValidityDuration = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);

    var textEncoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement
    {
        MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap11,
        WriteEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
        ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
        {
            MaxDepth = 32,
            MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue,
            MaxBytesPerRead = int.MaxValue,
            MaxNameTableCharCount = int.MaxValue,
            MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue
        }
    };

    var httpTransport = new HttpTransportBindingElement
    {
        ManualAddressing = false,
        MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue,
        MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
        AllowCookies = false,
        AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic,
       BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
        KeepAliveEnabled = true,
        MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue,
        ProxyAuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic,
       TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered,
       UseDefaultWebProxy = true,

    };

    var cc = new List<BindingElement> { security, textEncoding, httpTransport, };


  var client = new CAdxWebServiceXmlCCClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(new Uri(endpointAddress)));
   client.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new EndpointLoggingBehavior("EndpointLoggingBehavior"));



 client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "#username#";
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "#pwd#";
    var httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
        //****************request***************
        httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "text/xml; charset=utf-8");//application/soap+xml text/xml
        httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate");
        httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.KeepAlive, "true");
        httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Connection, "Keep-Alive");
        httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/12.0.1)");
    var authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName + ":" + client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password));

    httpRequestProperty.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + authInfo;
    httpRequestProperty.Method = "POST";

    var context = new OperationContext(client.InnerChannel);
    using (new OperationContextScope(context))
    {
        context.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;
      

        CAdxCallContext x3CallCtx = new CAdxCallContext
        {
            codeLang = "#lang#",
            poolAlias = "#pool#",
            requestConfig = "adxwss.optreturn=JSON&adxwss.beautify=true&adxwss.trace.on=off"
        };
      
        try
        {

            Console.Write("*****************************************");

            StringBuilder xmlInput = new StringBuilder(Cn_XMLHeader);
            xmlInput.Append("<PARAM>");
            xmlInput.Append("<GRP ID='GRP1' NAME='GRP1'>");
            xmlInput.AppendFormat("<FLD ID='YBPCORD' NAME='{0}'>{1}</FLD>", "YBPCORD", "#cod#");
            xmlInput.AppendFormat("<FLD ID='YDATE_CHAR' NAME='{0}'>{1}</FLD>", "YDATE_CHAR", "#date#");
            xmlInput.Append("</GRP>");
            xmlInput.Append("</PARAM>");
            var xmlString = xmlInput.ToString();
            //build the web service
            runRequest run = new runRequest
            {
                callContext = x3CallCtx,
                inputXml = xmlString,
                publicName = "#public#"
            };

            // Call web service
            var result =await client.runAsync(run);

            if (result != null)
                Console.WriteLine(result);

            return result.runReturn;

        }
        catch (TimeoutException timeProblem)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The service operation timed out. " + timeProblem.Message);
            client.Abort();
        }
        catch (FaultException ex)
        {
            client.Abort();

        }
        catch (CommunicationException e)

        {
            Console.WriteLine("Got {0}", e.GetType());
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace.ToString());
            client.Abort();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            client.Abort();
        }
```

and here the implementation of logging message before sending it

```
public class EndpointLoggingBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    public EndpointLoggingBehavior(string serviceName)
    {
        _serviceName = serviceName;
    }

    private readonly string _serviceName;

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint,
        System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(new MessageLoggingInspector(_serviceName));

    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class MessageLoggingInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    private readonly string _serviceName;

    protected string NodeToSignName => "xml";
    protected string SignatureNodeName => "Signature";

    public MessageLoggingInspector(string serviceName)
    {
        _serviceName = serviceName;
    }
    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        // copying message to buffer to avoid accidental corruption
        var buffer = reply.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue);
        reply = buffer.CreateMessage();
        // creating copy
        var copy = buffer.CreateMessage();
        //getting full input message
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (System.Xml.XmlWriter xw = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(sb))
        {
            copy.WriteMessage(xw);
            xw.Close();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Message Received:\n{0}", sb.ToString());
    }
    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        //request here is always reached with utf-16
//i tried to change it to utf-8 in this function with lot of methods but it never changed at the end

        return null;
    }


}
```

to more clarify the AfterReceiveReply() function worked and i can write the response in the console but continue debuging leads to CommunicationException **Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'run'.**

> **StackTrace :**    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, XmlSerializer serializer, MessagePartDescription returnPart, MessagePartDescriptionCollection bodyParts, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
> at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
> at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
> at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeReply(Message message, Object[] parameters)
> at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime.AfterReply(ProxyRpc& rpc)
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
> at BasicAuth.d__12.MoveNext() in F:\projects 2021\new project sage x3\ApiSageX3\SageWebService\SoapServices\BasicAuth.cs:line 278

> **InnerException** : There is an error in the XML document.
>
> **StackTrace** :    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
> at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, XmlSerializer serializer, MessagePartDescription returnPart, MessagePartDescriptionCollection bodyParts, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)

Comment: It is not the encoding.  Net requires UTF-8.  The best way of isolating  is to comment out all the XML classes and properties except the root element.  then slowly add back the commented out elements until you find error.  If the root by itself fails either the root name in class doesn't match the root name of xml. or the namespace in c# and xml do not match.

Comment: Looks like the problem is probably in `runAsync`. Please post a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: @StephenCleary the runAsync is generated from wcf service, by the way when i generated the wcf service from my wsdl link i can't select the Reuse type in referenced assemblies

Comment: @jdweng you mean by XML classes the auto generated code from wcf ? ok i will try it

Comment: Include the whole Exception, Details, inner exceptions and stack trace.

Comment: configure message logging: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/tracing-and-message-logging and verify what the xml looks like you get returned

Comment: @rene i updated my question with Exception details.. i am using .net5 i don't have Web.config file, i don't know if i can use this xml configs in .net core architecture

Comment: Did you try your AfterReply without this line `reply = buffer.CreateMessage();` I'm not 100% if it is needed in your usecase.

Comment: Yes.  The error is occurring during the deserialize of the xml.  The classes do not match xml.

Comment: @rene that afterReply() function was empty till i wanted to log the received message. Therror was always same

Comment: What does the console show when you have dumped that sb.ToString() to it?

Comment: It shows the expected message i want to be returned, but when i continue debugging it goes to communicationExeption shows that error i mentioned above

Comment: @jdweng it's auto generated how it can't be matched?

Comment: Don't ask me.  I do not know all the steps that were performed.  I just know the error is due to the classes not matching the xml.  Seen problem lots of times.  the xml and the classes are inconsistent.

Comment: Yes i understand, but do you have any idea how to fix that? I tried your suggestion about commenting xml classes slowly but i can't catch the problem where is it exactly

Comment: @jdweng thankyou so much i followed your instruction about commenting classes till find the issue and finally i found it, it was an attribute issue that can't be deserialized, i still don't know why it's not deserliazed but at least i can remove it everytime i generate the wcf. thank you again

Comment: Xml Deserialize errors are very hard to find.  Commenting is only way I've found of finding issues.

Comment: It is probably a namespace issue.